# Update Prepopulated database placed in Asset Folder

Tags: android, database, assets

My application have prepopulated database stored/ reside in asset folder under the resource folder.
I can read it .but how can i get a writeable database handle becoz i want to update that prepopulated database.

```
public Database_Opener(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
        }
        public void create_Database() throws IOException{
            boolean DBExists = checkDatabaseExistance();

            if(DBExists){

//              Do Nothing Becoz Database is Already Exists
                Log.i("Database", " Is Already Exists");
            }else{
//              Create and Copy Database 
                Log.i("Database", " Doesn't Exist and need to be Created");
//                              this is just a readable database handle
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                    copyDataBase();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    throw new Error("Error Copying Database");
                }
            }
            Log.i("Existing Database " ," IS successfully Opened");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the asset. You are welcome to update a copy of the asset that you create in internal storage (e.g., [`getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29)) or external storage.